# Scan with filter using HBase API (Java)

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I want to create a filter to return only the rows that contain a given field (or many fields).
My code :

```
FilterList flMaster = new FilterList(FilterList.Operator.MUST_PASS_ALL);
Filter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(Bytes.toBytes(CF1), Bytes.toBytes("RONAME"), CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL, Bytes.toBytes("roname1"));

scan.setFilter(flMaster);
scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(CF1));
scan.addFamily(Bytes.toBytes(CF2));

ResultScanner resultScanner = table.getScanner(scan);
```

and I create 2 records roname1 and roname2.

The problem is that the filter does not work: I get all lines (roname1 and roname2).

For informatio: hbase version : 1.0.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Filter filter = new ValueFilter(
        CompareFilter.CompareOp.EQUAL,
        new BinaryComparator(Bytes.toBytes("roman1")));
scan.setFilter(filter);
```